# UserManager Threading Issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to make sure a user is only assigned to a single role. So when they are assigned to a role, I am trying to iterate through all the other roles that they are a member and remove them. I am running into threading issues. Sometimes the exception says the thread is closed, sometimes it says "`A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe`", sometimes it works. Whats a better way to set this up?

```
public async void RemoveUserFromOtherSubscriptions(AppUser user, string subscriptionToKeep)
        {
            subscriptionToKeep = subscriptionToKeep.ToLower();
            string subscription;
            foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(SubcriptionTypes)))
            {
                //needed to change case to match bc all roles are sent .ToLower() before creation
                subscription = item.ToLower();
                var userIsInRole = await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, subscription); 
                if (userIsInRole && (subscription != subscriptionToKeep))
                {
                    //error is here
                    var result = await userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, subscription);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `RemoveUserFromOtherSubscriptions` is a  fire and forget method due to it being `void`. I don't think that is what you want. Change it from `void` to `Task` and then `await` it.

Comment: @JohanP That was it. Looks like maybe I've been up too late with this code :-)